# Call embeded font into label

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, fonts

Hey all i am trying to call my embedded font **AbrahamLincoln** into my label although when i run the program it never changes the font...

```
Private Sub slackerR_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim sMyFonts As String() = {"AbrahamLincoln.ttf"}
    Dim fEmbedded As New Font(GetFont(sMyFonts).Families(0), 10)
    Label1.Font = fEmbedded
End Sub

Public Function GetFont(ByVal FontResource() As String) As Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection
    'Get the namespace of the application    
    Dim NameSpc As String = Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name.ToString()
    Dim FntStrm As IO.Stream
    Dim FntFC As New Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To FontResource.GetUpperBound(0)
        'Get the resource stream area where the font is located
        FntStrm = Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(NameSpc + "." + FontResource(i))
        'Load the font off the stream into a byte array 
        Dim ByteStrm(CType(FntStrm.Length, Integer)) As Byte
        FntStrm.Read(ByteStrm, 0, Int(CType(FntStrm.Length, Integer)))
        'Allocate some memory on the global heap
        Dim FntPtr As IntPtr = Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(Byte)) * ByteStrm.Length)
        'Copy the byte array holding the font into the allocated memory.
        Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ByteStrm, 0, FntPtr, ByteStrm.Length)
        'Add the font to the PrivateFontCollection
        FntFC.AddMemoryFont(FntPtr, ByteStrm.Length)
        'Free the memory
        Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FreeHGlobal(FntPtr)
    Next
    Return FntFC
End Function
```

I've tried both **{"AbrahamLincoln.ttf"}** and **{"AbrahamLincoln"}** and both do not work.

Using VB.net 2010.

Comment: Look in the Output window for a "first chance exception" notification.

Comment: @HansPassant **of type 'System.NullReferenceException'** on the code line **Dim ByteStrm(CType(FntStrm.Length, Integer)) As Byte**

Comment: possible duplicate of [VS2010 does not show unhandled exception message in a WinForms Application on a 64-bit version of Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933958/vs2010-does-not-show-unhandled-exception-message-in-a-winforms-application-on-a)

Answer (score 1):

This may be an easier way for you...

Put font in your resources.

Add a module like this: (change the resource names below "My.Resources.[your resource name]")

```
Module agencyFontNormal
Private _pfc As PrivateFontCollection = Nothing
Public ReadOnly Property GetInstance(ByVal Size As Single, ByVal style As FontStyle) As Font
    Get
        If _pfc Is Nothing Then LoadFont()
        Return New Font(_pfc.Families(0), Size, style)
    End Get
End Property
Private Sub LoadFont()
    Try
        _pfc = New PrivateFontCollection
        Dim fontMemPointer As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(My.Resources.AGENCYNORMAL.Length)
        Marshal.Copy(My.Resources.AGENCYNORMAL, 0, fontMemPointer, My.Resources.AGENCYNORMAL.Length)
        _pfc.AddMemoryFont(fontMemPointer, My.Resources.AGENCYNORMAL.Length)
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(fontMemPointer)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
End Module
```

Call via:

```
Dim ff As Font = agencyFontNormal.GetInstance(12, FontStyle.Regular)
```